# How to set Dynamic Variable in Session and Cookies in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to store dynamic variable from external link `?dynamic=a_12_bc` and put into the link look like this `http://www.myweb.com?tracker=a_12_bc` 
First time it always show the dynamic link but when i refresh and click on other page it shows `?tracker=[object][Object]`.

```
<?php session_start(); 
 echo $_GET['dynamic'];
if( isset($_GET['dynamic']))
{
  $cookie_name = "dynamic";
  $cookie_value = $_GET['dynamic'];
  setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
  $_SESSION["dynamic"] = $cookie_value;
  }
else
{   
 $_SESSION["dynamic"] = $_COOKIE['dynamic'];
 }?>
 Button Link
<a href="https://www.myweb.com/?tracker=<?php echo($_SESSION['dynamic']);?>" target="_blank">LOG IN</button></a>
```

Can you please tell me how to maintain a session on other pages

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the cookie has been set, before assigning it to the session by adding isset() in your code.

```
if(isset($_GET['dynamic']))
{
   $cookie_name = "dynamic";
   $cookie_value = $_GET['dynamic'];
   setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
   $_SESSION["dynamic"] = $cookie_value;
}
else if(isset($_COOKIE['dynamic'])) {
   $_SESSION["dynamic"] = $_COOKIE['dynamic'];
}
else
{
   //something here
}
```

if the cookie is not set, try adding the domain in setcookie() method,

```
setcookie( $cookie_name , $cookie_value , time() + (86400 * 30), '/', COOKIE_DOMAIN );
```

If you need more information you can refer this link https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/set-get-delete-cookies